# Python-Map function not doing what I expected

Tags: python, python-3.x

Map is not working. Please help! I've tried:

```
print(map("1", "6"))
```

but it only returns

```
<map object at 0x0000023C0BE565C0>
```

and i've also tried:

```
print(map([1, 6]))
```

but it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fuyul\OneDrive\桌面\sameon.py", line 1, in <module>
    print(map([1, 6]))
TypeError: map() must have at least two arguments
```

What do I do?

Comment: Maybe you meant `zip`?

Comment: What did you expect? These `map` calls don't make sense.

Comment: `map` takes a function and an iterable of things and and returns an iterator of f(thing1), f(thing2), f(thing3), etc. That's nothing like what you're doing. I don't have any good guesses what you might be trying to do.

Comment: For zip it executes similarly: <zip object at 0x00000298357170C0>

Comment: It seems like you want to do something that doesn't involve the `map` function at all.  What output were you hoping to get?

Comment: What a result do you expect?

Comment: Do you maybe just want `print(1, 6)`?

Comment: What are you using `map` for?

Comment: I don't know anything about map

Comment: map() function returns a map object(which is an iterator) of the results after applying the given function to each item of a given iterable (list, tuple etc.).  The map function signature is map(fun, iter).  You have only given the function the iter parameter, so it is doing nothing and returning a map object as expected>  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Walt: explain what you're trying to do without using the word `map`.  :)

Comment: Can you explain the expected output? `map` applies a function to an iterable. The first argument should be a function. The second argument should be an iterable of values that are being passed to the function. subsequent arguments should also be iterables; they should be the second, third, etc. arguments to the function.

Comment: How do I make it return a number/str?

Comment: Does `print(1)` do what you're looking for?

Comment: It's the most amusing thread ever.

Comment: this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice..  If you don'[t know what the map function is, read the docs.

Comment: ok  \\\\\\....\\\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
map(int, ['1', '6'])
```

This will return a map object, which is an iterable.

```
result = map(int, ['1', '6'])
list(result)
```

will probably be enlightening.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use the `map` function at all.  To print a number, just pass it to `print`, e.g.:

```
print(1)
```

You can also print a sequence of numbers:

```
print(1, 6)
```